# ARKit - How to make 3d model glossy?

Tags: ios, arkit

I'm working with ARKit, I want my model look more realistic by using this code:

```
self.sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
self.sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true
```

But this code not make my model like metal material (glossy). How to make the material look like metal? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Duc Phan - I think your really asking for how to make a object shinny or glossy. I will use sceneKit to explain.

First take a look at this nice graphic that explains sceneKit's node based framework:
[sceneKit Node Based Framework](https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2014/09/SceneGraph1.png)

Now take a look at this code and see if it helps you out.

```
// create a node object
let ballNode = SCNNode()

// create a geometery object 
// notice the after firstMaterial is [diffuse][2] and [specular][3]
// this sets the shading attributes that define the appearance of a 
// geometry's surface when rendered    
let ballGeometery = SCNSphere(radius: 0.5)
  ballGeometry.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
  ballGeometry.firstMaterial!.specular.contents = UIColor.white

// attached the geometry to the node
 ballNode.geometry = ballGeometry

// add ballNode to sceneViews scene's rootNode
 sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ballNode)
```

Please note there are many way to set the geometry's surface when rendered - [SCNMaterial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial)

I hope this helps.

Enjoy ARKit!